# How can I call a method from another namespace and pass data

Tags: xamarin, methods, bitmap, gallery

I want to pass an SKImage and a string filename to save the picture to phone's directory.

The method what I am trying to call:

```
namespace LevelMeter.Droid
{
    public class SaveImage_Droid : SaveImage
    {
        public SaveImage_Droid(SKImage snapshot, string fileName)
        {
            SaveImage(snapshot, fileName);
        }

        public void SaveImage(SKImage snapshot, string fileName)
        {
            var pictures = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;

            Bitmap bm = snapshot.ToBitmap();

            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pictures, fileName);
            var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            bm.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 90, stream);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I made this interface:

```
namespace LevelMeter
{
    public interface SaveImage
    {
        void SaveImage(SKImage snapshot, string fileName);
    }
}
```

And I want to call it from

```
namespace LevelMeter.Views
{
    public void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SKImage snapshot = surface.Snapshot();
        string fileName = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg";
        SaveImage(snapshot, fileName); //I cant't reach it
    }
}
```

Comment: you should be able to do that directly in your .NET Standard project, there is no need to do it in the Android project

Comment: But Bitmap is using Android.Graphics, is there another way?

Comment: Skia can create the jpg for you

Comment: Thank you. I got it, and how can I the Android.OS.Enviroment.GetExternalStorage.... part in my standard project?

Comment: Tried `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/registration-and-resolution#resolve-the-platform-implementations) to call method from shared project to `.Android` project:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SKImage snapshot = surface.Snapshot();
        string fileName = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg";

        DependencyService.Get<ISaveImage>().SaveImage(snapshot, fileName);
    }
}

public interface ISaveImage
{
    void SaveImage(SKImage snapshot, string fileName);
}
```

And in Android project, register it: [Registration by attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/registration-and-resolution#registration-by-attribute)

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SaveImage_Droid))]
namespace LevelMeter.Droid
{
    public class SaveImage_Droid : SaveImage
    {
        public SaveImage_Droid(SKImage snapshot, string fileName)
        {
            SaveImage(snapshot, fileName);
        }

        public void SaveImage(SKImage snapshot, string fileName)
        {
            var pictures = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;

            Bitmap bm = snapshot.ToBitmap();

            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pictures, fileName);
            var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            bm.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 90, stream);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```